# How to print SYS_REFCURSOR with PLSQLDeveloper window?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

In the below query how to get IO_CURSOR values in PL/SQL's "SQL Window"

```
DECLARE
  SOME_VAR_1 VARCHAR2(20);
  SOME_VAR_2 VARCHAR2(20);
  SOME_VAR_3 DECIMAL;
  IO_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  SOME_VAR_1 := 'test1';
  SOME_VAR_2 := 'test2';
  SOME_VAR_3 := 1;
  IO_CURSOR := NULL;
  Get_Analysis_Data(p_in_symbol_type => SOME_VAR_1,
                    p_in_symbol => SOME_VAR_2, 
                    p_in_isr_id => SOME_VAR_3,
                    isr_main_view => IO_CURSOR);
  PRINT IO_CURSOR
END;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "SQL Window" you mean SQL*PLUS ,then to print(using `PRINT` command) the contents of a cursor, you need to declare a bind variable outside the PL/SQL block, assign a value to that bind variable inside the PL/SQL block by executing the block and then print the contents by using `PRINT` command:

```
SQL> variable  IO_CURSOR refcursor;

SQL> DECLARE
  2    SOME_VAR_1 VARCHAR2(20);
  3    SOME_VAR_2 VARCHAR2(20);
  4    SOME_VAR_3 DECIMAL;
  5    --IO_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
  6    BEGIN
  7      SOME_VAR_1 := 'test1';
  8      SOME_VAR_2 := 'test2';
  9      SOME_VAR_3 := 1;
  10     --IO_CURSOR := NULL;  -- no need to do that
  11     Get_Analysis_Data(p_in_symbol_type => SOME_VAR_1,
  12                       p_in_symbol => SOME_VAR_2, 
  13                       p_in_isr_id => SOME_VAR_3,
  14                       isr_main_view => :IO_CURSOR);
  15   END;
  16 /

  SQL> print io_cursor;
```

**EDIT**:

To see the contents of a cursor in PL/SQL Developer, as one of the options, you could simply do the following:

1. File\New\Test window
2. Copy/Paste your anonymous PL/SQL block there. Prior to this remove `IO_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;` variable declaration. There is no need of it. Also change `isr_main_view => IO_CURSOR`  to `isr_main_view => :IO_CURSOR`. You need to use bind variable in this case.
3. In the `variables window` at the bottom of the `test window` specify variable name of your ref cursor the contents of which you want to see (`IO_CURSOR` without preceding semicolon ) and select type `cursor`.
4. Execute the block by pressing green triangle.
5. After PL/SQL block is executed refer to the column `value` of the `variables window`. Press the button with ellipsis on it to see the contents of the ref cursor `IO_CURSOR`.

Comment: seems like he means allroundautomations' plsql developer IDE

Comment: Sorry, got confused with the IDE names (see the edit in my post)

Comment: @Jakob In PL/SQL developer you can use `test window` to see the content of a ref cursor as well as any other variable.Answer has been edited.

Comment: @Nicholas Thx, I did'n know :)

Answer (score 1):

If **Get_Analysis_Data** is a stored procedure you can execute it by opening it and using the "Run" command (the green arrow in your toolbar). The content of the refcursor is printed in the "Variables Output" window like a table.

A brief tutorial can be found here: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/12/sql-developer-tip-viewing-refcursor-output/

EDIT:

Sorry, got confused with the IDE-Tools names. This answer applies only if you are using [Oracle SQL-Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).... If you don't use it i suggest you to switch asap :)