# execute stored procedure with out ref_cursor in sql navigator

Tags: sql, oracle, ref-cursor, sql-navigator

I am new to Oracle and sql navigator. I can't seem to find a way to execute a stored proc and see its results. The proc is created as follows. How do I execute this proc in sql navigator. I am using sql navigator 6.7. Also, please be advised that the proc is using out ref-cursor.

```
PROCEDURE getdata
( p_id            IN VARCHAR2,
 p_date            IN DATE,
 p_out   OUT ref_cursor)
IS

BEGIN
 OPEN p_out FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   OPS_ARW.logs
    WHERE   member_id = p_id 
    AND     date>p_date;

END;
```

PS: I am pretty sure this is a duplicate. Would appreciate if you can only redirect me to the correct place as I can't find it.

Comment: Should your out parameter be declared as a SYS_REFCURSOR?

Comment: I have no idea. I am extremely new to oracle. I just want to run this proc and see the result. I can't make change to the proc though.

Comment: I am unable to do this with [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) but I found another question related to your question on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110842/how-to-print-sys-refcursor-with-plsqldeveloper-window).

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time after the question, but as I spend a lot of time to build this code, here my running solution for a similar problem. Note: my procedure returns the columns **id**, **codboard**, **descrboard**, and **TABNUM**. I am using Sql Navigator:

```
declare
l_list_boards sys_refcursor;
l_id          number;
l_codboard    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
l_descrboard  VARCHAR2(250 BYTE);
l_TABNUM      NUMBER;
begin

    PACK_NAME.GetBoardsList(list_boards=> l_list_boards);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Results: ');  

    loop
        fetch l_list_boards into l_id, l_codboard, l_descrboard, l_TABNUM;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_descrboard);
        EXIT WHEN l_list_boards%NOTFOUND;
    end loop;

    close l_list_boards;
end;
```