# Can anyone help whey my execption section is not working,

Tags: oracle11g

My whole intention to catch exception,WRONG parameter is NOT CATCHING exception. 
Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE list_emp (p_emp_id IN employees.employee_id%TYPE,
                                      p_dept_id IN employees.department_id%TYPE)

IS
CURSOR c1 IS 
          SELECT * 
          FROM EMPLOYEES
          WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=p_emp_id
          AND   DEPARTMENT_ID=p_dept_id;
 emp_rec  c1%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
    LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO emp_rec;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_rec.employee_id||' '||emp_rec.first_name||' '||emp_rec.last_name);
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Record Found ');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Record Found ');
END;
```

Comment: do you need the cursor?why not just use `select ... into` directly?

Comment: Hi Brenners; Really appreciate your response, isn't it select ... into for scalar, what happened  my parameter has multiple rows, if i am wrong can your show how would i use select ... into in this proc--please help me to understand

Comment: can you edit your post so that we can see the code clearly

Comment: how are you sure that the exception block is not being called? Are you using TOAD or SQL developer? Also were you able to compile your procedure successfully

Comment: SQL Developer, 11g R2, when i execute with --correct parameter:anonymous block completed
222 David Smith
--And Wrong parameter
anonymous block completed; Yes Compile successful

Comment: I'd recommend you use a cursor-for-loop instead of old-fashioned explicit cursors.  That is, use something like `for remp_rec in (select ...) loop ... end loop;` and throw out all the CURSOR/OPEN/FETCH/CLOSE code.  Cursor-for-loops are simpler and much faster.

Answer (score 1):

When the cursor is opened and fetched with the wrong parameter that does not match any row from the corresponding table, the following line

```
 EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
```

cause the plsql procedure to terminate (because there were no rows found). Hence no exception is raised.

If you do want to display some sort of output you can do the following instead

```
IF c1%FOUND THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Record Found');
ELSE
     dbms_output.put_line('Finished/Done');
     EXIT;
END IF;
```

Comment: Under Exception block?

Comment: Thank you very much , help me to understand

Comment: if this has helped, please accept this as an answer so that i does not show in the unanswered list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to raise an error after looping through a cursor that returns no rows, then you're going to have to use a counter to work out how many rows have been processed, and then you can do something if no rows have been processed.

Something like:

```
create or replace procedure list_emp (p_emp_id in employees.employee_id%type,
                                      p_dept_id in employees.department_id%type)

is
  cursor c1 is 
    select employee_id,
           first_name,
           last_name
    from   employees
    where  employee_id = p_emp_id
    and    department_id = p_dept_id;

  v_count number := 0;
begin
  for emp_rec in c1
  loop
    v_count := v_count + 1;
    dbms_output.put_line(emp_rec.employee_id||' '||emp_rec.first_name||' '||emp_rec.last_name);
  end loop;

  if v_count = 0 then
    raise no_data_found;
  end if;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No Record Found.');
    raise;
  when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line('An error occurred: '||sqlerrm);
    raise;
end;
/
```

A few notes:

- I converted your cursor loop into a cursor-for-loop; you don't need to worry about declaring the record type and also Oracle handles the opening and closing of the cursor for you.
- I added `raise;` to each of your exception handlers - in general, having when others then null (which is effectively what your original code was doing - no errors are raised to the calling code) is a bad idea. I added the raise to the no_data_found condition as that wasn't doing anything either; typically, if you have an exception condition, you want it to do something to let the calling code know there was a problem (not always, of course; sometimes you don't want the processing to stop if a particular error condition is met).
- Your cursor was selecting all columns, but in your procedure, you were only using three of them. I've therefore amended the cursor so that it only pulls back those three columns.
- Don't rely on dbms_output in your production code. Code that calls this procedure won't see anything populated in dbms_output, unless it explicitly looks for it - and that's not something I've ever seen in any production code, outside of Database tools (eg. SQL*Plus, Toad, etc). I've left this in your procedure as I've a feeling this is a learning exercise for you, but please don't think that this is in any way acceptable in production code.
- You're passing `p_emp_id` in as a parameter - typically, that's the primary key of the employees table. If that's the case, then there's no need for the cursor for loop at all - you could do it by using `select ... into ...` instead, like so:

.

```
create or replace procedure list_emp (p_emp_id in employees.employee_id%type,
                                      p_dept_id in employees.department_id%type)

is
  v_emp_id employees.employee_id%type;
  v_first_name employees.first_name%type;
  v_last_name employees.last_name%type;
begin
  select employee_id,
         first_name,
         last_name
  into   v_emp_id,
         v_first_name,
         v_last_name
  from   employees
  where  employee_id = p_emp_id
  and    department_id = p_dept_id;

  dbms_output.put_line(emp_rec.employee_id||' '||emp_rec.first_name||' '||emp_rec.last_name);
exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No Record Found.');
    raise;
  when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line('An error occurred: '||sqlerrm);
    raise;
end;
/
```

---

Alternatively, just pass back a ref cursor:

```
create or replace procedure list_emp (p_emp_id in employees.employee_id%type,
                                      p_dept_id in employees.department_id%type,
                                      p_ref_cur out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
  open p_ref_cur for select employee_id,
                            first_name,
                            last_name
                     from   employees
                     where  employee_id = p_emp_id
                     and    department_id = p_dept_id;
  -- No need for an exception handler here since you're not storing the error details anyway.
  -- By not having an error handler, any error will automatically be raised up to the calling code
  -- and it will have the correct error stack trace info (e.g. the line number the error occurred,
  -- rather than the line the error was reraised from
end;
/
```

And to run the ref cursor in SQL*Plus (or as a script in Toad/SQL Developer/etc), you do the following:

```
-- create a variable outside of PL/SQL to hold the ref cursor pointer (this is a SQL*Plus command):
variable rc refcursor;

-- populate our ref cursor variable with the pointer. Note how we pass it in as a bind variable
begin
  list_emp(p_emp_id => 1234,
           p_dept_id => 10,
           p_ref_cur => :rc);
end;
/

-- finally, print the contents of the ref cursor.
print rc;
```

Comment: Hi Boneist, Amazing, I really loved it, that is exactly I wanted to know, how would I work around--Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Boneist, One more question please, How would I user header line before my display, can you suggest please

Comment: sorry I meant "Use" not User

Comment: What's the actual purpose of this stored proc? If it's merely to run a query on the db and use the results elsewhere (e.g. in Java/C#/VB etc code), then don't bother looping through the results in the stored proc - instead, open a ref cursor and then pass that back, so that the calling code can loop through the results itself. If you just wanted to print the results of the ref cursor in SQL*Plus/SQL Developer/Toad/etc, then use the variable and print commands - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110842/how-to-print-sys-refcursor-with-plsqldeveloper-window) for an example.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the ref cursor example.

Comment: Lets say my employee_id is not PK, so there might be possibility, My passing parameter has multiple record, it will through an error you SELECT..INTO Method, right? is there any way,can I return multiple record by using  SELECT..INTO method,(what I know it works only in scalar )

Comment: If you're not filtering on the primary key (which may be employee_id, department_id, of course!) then `select ... into ...` is not going to be of use, so you're going to have to use a cursor. In that case, I'd probably go for the ref cursor solution, assuming that this is a procedure that's going to be called by external code. If you had to display a header row and you're using the cursor for loop + dbms_output, it's just a matter of adding in another dbms_output.put_line along with the text you wish to display either inside or before the loop, depending on if you always want to see it or not.